# Clear content and copy from another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written a script that intends to clear the content of a Google Sheets spreadsheet and copy and paste the content of another sheet.

The sheet that needs to be cleared is called "NEW_SHEET" and the one to be copied over is called "Database".

For some reason, the script is not working at the moment. Nothing happens when I run it.
Also, at the moment, I am using `.getActiveRange` to select the range to clear. However, I would like that to be columns A to AC and only to the last row with data in it.

This is the code I am using:

```
function importDB() {
  //Delete content of New Sheet
  var sh1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET_ID').getSheetByName('NEW_SHEET')
  var range1 = sh1.getActiveRange()
  range1.clearContent()

  //Copy new database data
 var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET_ID').getSheetByName('Database')
   var range = sh.getDataRange();  
   var data = range.getValues();
   var ts = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET_ID').getSheetByName('NEW_SHEET')
   ts.setValues(data)
}
```

Comment: And? What alternatives to `getActiveRange` have you tried? There are several that you should  have found during your pre-question research. You also don't indicate how this function is called.

Comment: I have also tried `getDataRange` which also didn't work. It's only the `importDB ()` function. Thank you!

Comment: "didn't work" is not adequate when seeking help. Errors? When you debug, what does the object actually become, and what did you expect it to be? Your responsibility is to convert exactly what you have done and exactly how it does not accomplish what you're intending to do.

Comment: Note that your `setValues` call should be on a `Range` object but you attempt to call it from a `Sheet` object. I would expect an error to be thrown here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `getActiveRange()` here. The code below should work.

```
function importDB() {
  //Delete contents of "A:AC" in New Sheet
  var sh1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET_ID').getSheetByName('NEW_SHEET').getRange("A:AC");
  sh1.clearContent();

  //Copy new database data
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET_ID').getSheetByName('Database');
  var range = sh.getDataRange();  
  range.copyTo(sh1.getCell(1,1));
}
```

With the `copyTo()` function, you [only the first cell in the destination matters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination). So you need to be careful that the data being copied from "Database" doesn't extend past column AC, otherwise you'll be overwriting that data in "NEW_SHEET". To prevent that, you could try `var range = sh.getRange("A:AC")` rather than copying over the entire data range.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had to make a few tweaks to your code because the source and target sheets were not part of the same spreadsheet file. So I had to use `setValues` instead of `range.copyTo`. But your code worked perfectly aside from that.