# How to copy sheet content to another sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to copy a `sheet#1` content to override the content of another `sheet#2`, but without deleting `sheet#2` as my code currently does.

Is there any API to do so?

```
  newGSheet.getSheets()[0].copyTo(oldGSheet);
  
  var oldSheet = oldGSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  if (oldSheet != null) {
 oldGSheet.deleteSheet(oldSheet);
    oldGSheet.getSheetByName('Copy of Sheet1').setName('Sheet1');
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [Clear content and copy from another sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49628746/1595451)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

The logic would be quite simple.

- You get the data `newData` of the new sheet `newSheet` which is a 2D array.
- You check if `Sheet1` exists in the old spreadsheet `oldGSheet`. If it does not exist, copy `newSheet` to `oldGSheet` and name it `Sheet1`. If `Sheet1` exists already, then clear its contents and paste (set) `newData` to it.

---

### Solution:

```
  const newSheet = newGSheet.getSheets()[0];
  // get the data of newSheet
  const newData = newSheet.getRange(1,1,newSheet.getLastRow(),newSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const oldSheet = oldGSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  
  // if Sheet1 does not exists, then create it.
  // if Sheet1 exists, clear its contents and paste newData
  
  if(oldSheet == null){
  newSheet.copyTo(oldGSheet).setName('Sheet1');
  }
  else {
  oldSheet.clearContents();
  oldSheet.getRange(1,1,newData.length,newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
  }
```